# Netbeans 7.4 - exclude LESS partial source files from compiling to css

Tags: html, css, netbeans, less

This is mostly a nuisance problem (creating clutter in my css directory). I want to know if, in Netbeans 7.4 (or 8.0 beta?), there is any way to tag a LESS file to no be compiled on run/save.

I have a library.less and vars.less file that are .mixins and @variables that get used site-wide in several other less files as includes but don't need to be compiled themselves as they produce effectively empty CSS.

I'd like Netbeans OR lessc.cmd to ignore them if possible. Is it something that can be done?

Comment: I worked out a way around this. LESS I want compiling to CSS goes in /less/css and anything else is in /less/lib - the compiler is set to ONLY act on the contents of /less/css, l;eaving my lib files uncompiled. Huzzah!

Comment: It also required me to use --include-path=PATH1;PATH2 to include the files I wasn't compiling on save into the CSS files. a little bit tricky but it works great. You can set this below where you add paths in the LESS setup for each project in NetBeans.

Comment: FOLLOWUP: I realized one minor(?) flaw with this. If I alter a compiled less/css file it recompiles. If I alter a less/lib file it *doesn't* recompile and I have to trigger it manually for all the less/css files I have it included in. A bummer if I change something in my site-wide variables file that is inlcuded everywhere :\

While I'm really stoked NetBeans has LESS compiler support, it's clear they need to consider a more complex way of handling LESS source and includes etc.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [test suite](http://wiki.netbeans.org/TS_74_LessSupport#Test_suite%3a_Compile_on_save), editing and saving a partial should trigger a recompile for the parent file with the @include, but it doesn't say anything about excluding the partial itself from preprocessing. My experience is similar to yours.

There's a bug report for the feature here:
https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=239593

Annoying because the feature was requested back in December 2013, and 8.0 was released in March 2014.

Comment: Does this feature require the path of the included partial to be resolvable from the main file? If so then my method above breaks that function, which is frightfully annoying.

Comment: I think so. The idea is that it should work the same way as sass/scss partials (files with leading underscore are not compiled into their own files).