# Netbeans 8.0 Yii Project Bootstrap LESS files have errors

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, netbeans, yii, less

In my Yii project I have the YiiStrap extension that uses Twitter Bootstrap.

The assets folder contains a LESS subfolder, however many of the less files are getting errors saying they were unable to be parsed.

On entering the affected files (not all LESS files are affected, for some reason, only about a third), I see certain lines that have "Unexpected token WS found" next to them. See the image here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OjiRM.jpg

I believe this is what is causing parts of my project to not render and act properly. For example, I am trying to use the responsive YiiStrap Navbar with dropdowns, the dropdowns do not do what they should, menu items do not highlight properly, and the collapse function is hit-or-miss.

I've searched around, but there seems to be no definitive answer to this already. Does anybody have any clue?

Note: In Netbeans 8.0, I have installed a LESS compiler from the Node.JS NPM command prompt, and a SASS compiler from the Ruby gem command prompt.

Answer (score 1):

You have to configure your IDE to compile only the main less file: bootstrap.less which includes all other less files.

Errors occurs mainly because some less files use mixins and variables from mixins.less and variables.less files.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Would you mind instructing me on how to do that on Netbeans? I'm assuming that it's somewhere in Options?

Comment: I'm not sure if this feature implemented in Netbeans yet. It's discussed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21779644/netbeans-7-4-exclude-less-partial-source-files-from-compiling-to-css

Anyway, you can use Jetbrains PhpStorm

Answer (score 1):

That's error in less parser in NetBeans, it shouldn't cause any troubles when compiling to css. Anyway, on your screenshot, you can see the bulb icon, click on it and you can hide all these errors from file/folder/parent folders or project as such.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Indeed, my webpage loads fine when in use. However, the widgets used in this extension (that would naturally use these less files) don't seem to render correctly when compared to the examples on the YiiStrap website. Do you have any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know Yii